# Traveling from Canada to Australia with a layover in New Zealand. Will I go through AUS customs in New Zealand?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia, short-connections, new-zealand, pre-clearance

I'm a Canadian citizen traveling from YYC to MEL with 2 layovers one in LAX and one in AKL. In Canada when we travel to the states we do US customs/immigration in Canada because that section of the airport is considered the 'USA' so that way we technically enter domestically.

I'm curious if it's the same for Australia and New Zealand? And will I need to do AUS customs/immigration upon landing in Auckland? I only have 1.15 hours during my layover and am a little worried it won't be enough time to recheck my luggage and change terminals if that's the case.

I'm planning on staying in AUS for a year so I'm anticipating it won't be a quick in and out through immigration.

If anyone knows the answer please share and help ease my concerns, my flight still isn't for a month so I can try to make changes if it's necessary.

Comment: Pre-clearance is a very US-centric thing. You'll pass through passport control in Australia. Also, your luggage should be checked in all the way (at least from LAX) to MEL.

Comment: dda that looks like an answer, can you please post it as such?

Comment: This is NZ. The Ozzies across the ditch are our great cobbas, usually, but they can keep their customs clearance where it belongs. We don't shill for them, nor they for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have travelled in and out of Australia and New Zealand several times in the past few years. In my experience both Customs & Immigration clearance for Australia will be done on arrival in Australia. They don’t do pre-clearance. Your bags should be interlined through to your Australian entry airport.

Australian Customs controls are quite thorough. They are very concerned about  folk bringing in prohibited foodstuffs, seeds etc, in case they are carrying diseases not yet found in Oz. Your airline will give you a landing card to complete which asks you to list everything of that nature you have, and you’ll likely get a face to face interview with a Border Control Officer on arrival who will assess whether your bags need searched for prohibited foodstuffs.